# Go: unexpected EOF while reading from a socket

Tags: sockets, go, eof

I have the following simple golang program to download Google's privacy policy. Unfortunately it always crashes with the error `unexpected EOF` after reading 6861 bytes, even though the document is much longer. Why?

```
package main

import "net"
import "fmt"
import "io"
import "os"

func die(msg string, s os.Error) {
    fmt.Printf("%s crashed: %v\n", msg, s)
    os.Exit(1)
}

func main() {
    fd, err := net.Dial("tcp", "google.com:80")
    if err != nil { die("dial", err) }

    req := []byte("GET /intl/en/privacy/ HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n")
    _, err = fd.Write(req)
    if err != nil { die("dial write", err) }

    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    nr := 1

    for nr > 0 {
        nr, err = io.ReadFull(fd, buf)
        if err != nil { die("dial read", err) }
        fmt.Printf("read %d\n", nr)
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
read 1024
read 1024
read 1024
read 1024
read 1024
read 1024
dial read crashed: unexpected EOF
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Function `io.ReadFull(fd, buf)` should be used only when you **know** that `fd` can feed **at least** `len(buf)` bytes.

Instead, try the following:

```
var buf bytes.Buffer

nr, err := io.Copy(&buf, fd)
if err != nil {
    die("dial read", err)
}
```

If copying to a file, use an `os.File` instead of `bytes.Buffer`.

Answer (score 4):

You can also get the size of the file from the HTTP headers, and read to that length on your socket. Look for Content-Length response header.

You should always know the size of what you are moving with IO, when it's a file and possible, and limit your read to the expected size. This will avoid a lot of issues.
pseudocode:

```
$size = HTTP_RESPONSE['Content-Length'];
while(reading to $size)
{
    do something with chunk;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The document is not much longer. It's only 412 bytes longer. Sine [ReadFull](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadFull) cannot read all 1024 bytes it returns `unexpected EOF`.